# Linking three Models with many to many links between all Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I've been struggling with this for a few days.

I have three models that link together with many to many relationships.

Rules:

- A requirement can have many controls and vice versa
- A procedure can have many controls and vice versa

I am currently showing all controls linked to requirements in my requirements views without a problem and i've even got the create / update working through the creation of viewmodels that hold the assigned data

I'd like to show the list of all procedures that are linked to the controls which are linked to the requirement I am viewing. I won't want to edit them at that level as that will be done through the control Controller. It's a link through two join tables that i'm unable figure out :(

Models:

```
public class Requirement
{
    [Key]
    public int RequirementId { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Control> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class Control
{
    public int ControlId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Requirement> Requirements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Procedure> Procedures { get; set; }
}

public class Procedure
{
    [Key]
    public int ProcedureId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Control> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

Dbcontext:

```
public class CompliancePortalContext : DbContext
{
    public CompliancePortalContext()
        : base("CompliancePortalContext")
    { }

    public DbSet<Control> Controls { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Procedure> Procedures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Requirement> Requirements { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Procedure>().HasMany(c => c.Controls).WithMany(p => p.Procedures).Map(
            mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("ProcedureId");
                mc.MapRightKey("ControlId");
                mc.ToTable("ProcedureControl");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Requirement>().HasMany(c => c.Controls).WithMany(r => r.Requirements).Map(
            mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("RequirementId");
                mc.MapRightKey("ControlId");
                mc.ToTable("RequirementControl");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you all the procedures linked to all the controls linked to all requirements.

```
from r in Requirements
from c in r.Controls
from p in c.Procedures
select p
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. I have a lot to learn! Thanks Fredrik :)